# Unwanted symbol showing in Android 2.3, either through li or ul tag

Tags: android, html, css

I have a list of social icons displayed at the top of my site which is showing unwanted symbols in **Android 2.3**. Can't for the life of me work out why....

I've eliminated the likelihood of it being the `<a>` tags, and the CSS attached to those.

Any idea?

I've removed code I know isn't the cause:

**HTML**

```
<section class="grid-3 grid-flow-opposite social-icons">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="facebook" href="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a class="twitter" href="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a class="youtube" href="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a class="linkedin" href="#" target="_blank"></a></li>
        <li><a class="email" href="#"></a></a></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

**CSS(Sass)**

```
.social-icons {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    margin: 0;
    ul {
        position: relative;
        left: 80px;
        text-align: left;
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            zoom: 1;
            *display: inline;
            padding-left: 2%;
            a {
                position: relative;
                display: block;
                width: 35px;
                height: 35px;
                .no-svg & {
                    &.facebook { background: url(../img/icons-facebook.png) no-repeat center; }
                    ******* etc... etc....
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: Link images removed from CSS for clarity]

(Link images removed from CSS for clarity)

All fairly basic right.... is there some known issue or default behaviour with **Android 2.3** and li tags?

Comment: it's the CSS and display: inline-block; imparticular....not sure why

Answer (score 0):

Removed `text-rendering: optimizeLegibility`, fixed